# Error attaching volume to amazon ec2 instance

Tags: linux, unix, amazon-ec2

error attaching volume to ec2 instance.

Error attaching volume: Value (/etc/sda1) for parameter device is invalid. /etc/sda1 is not a valid EBS device name.

lsblk gives

```
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda 202:0 0 10G 0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1 0 10G 0 part /
xvdf 202:80 0 10G 0 disk /mnt/sdf
```

Comment: Please write complete sentences. Ideally, one of them should actually be a question.

Answer (score 0):

EC2 is running a modified Xen that emulates more devices as device partitions, sda1, sda2, sda3, sda4 and like that for more letters.  It creates these around the whole device names without numbers, which are not available for use.  So you need to attach a volume as one of the four partitions for each whole device.  Some are already used for the system, so skip over those as well.  It is best to attach starting at sde1 and beyond.  This is for paravirtual (pv) instance.  hvm instances work the other way and you need to target whole device names without partition numbers for attaching.

Comment: Tried attaching as /etc/sde1 . getting this error .Error attaching volume: Value (/etc/sde1) for parameter device is invalid. /etc/sde1 is not a valid EBS device name.